# Android: Run an app when it's definitively closed

Tags: java, android, background

I noted that when I close my app definitively, the method `runInBackGround` of the class `MultiplyTask` stops working. It works when the activity is in the phase `STOP` or `PAUSE`, but when I close my app, the method finishes ( it's a loop created with a cycle `while(true) {...}` ). 
How can for example Whatsapp send notifications though it's closed? I want to create a similar thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is closed, all code will stop running.  If you are looking to execute while the app is open and continue executing code while the app is closed, you will want to look into [using a Service.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Take a thorough look at the Service documentation and it will hopefully be what you are looking for.
Services are also killed when your app is closed, but using the START_STICKY return value you can make sure your service is restarted upon termination.

EDIT WITH MORE INFORMATION:

```
<service
    android:name="MyService" />
```

Add the above to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          // This is where you would place your code that you want in the background
          // Putting your while loop here will make sure it runs when the app is closed
          return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
  }
}
```

Create a new class with the above code.

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

Call this code from your launcher Activity to start the service when the app is launched.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I use this START_STICKY?

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is ideal for short operation which are needed to be performed in the background. Usually Asyntask is implemented as sub class of activity which is destroyed when app is close. Also It communicates with the UI thread at some points ... so It needs the activity to be in memory... For long running operation, Service is better. Some Apps notify user even when they are not running. In fact they have one or more services running in background. You can see those in your phone setting->apps menu. 
Study [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for more information about services.